# GET call works in Postman but not in cURL

Tags: curl, postman

---

I have a simple call to a service that works on Postman:
[image]

Bbut doesn't work if I call it from CLI with the cURL code that Postman gives me, even the ping command says that the host could not be resolved:

[image]

Why something could works on Postman but not in CLI, even pinging?

Comment: Likely explanations include (1) a typo in the URL and (2) you're running  cloud version of postman and the network is different there to the machine you're running curl on.

Comment: ok. Postman is the regular desktop app for Mac, and typo can't be, the curl is copy-pasted from what Postman gives me. But thanks

Comment: This will be a network connectivity issue.  Requests from the CLI will be sent from a Postman IP address.  Are there are any access control lists on the firewall protecting that API that might be blocking access?  If this is the issue, then the Enterprise licenses allow you a static IP.  However, I would expect a different error than unknown host in this instance.  Ping is sometimes blocked on servers.  Can you ping this from your desktop?  If you can, then you should be able to ping from the CLI.  You could also try an nslookup (dns lookup) instead of a ping.